# a post with border and no border using for or if in django

Tags: django, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

models.py:

```
class post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='somewhere/dir')
    active_post = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    commercial_post = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    normal_post = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    post_with_colored_border = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    post_title_bold = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    post_with_border_and_title_bold = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    posts= post.objects.filter(active_post=True)
    normal_post = posts.filter(normal_post=True)
    commercial_post = posts.filter(commercial_post=True)
    post_with_border = posts.filter(post_with_colored_border=True)
    post_title_bold = posts.filter(post_title_bold=True)
    post_with_border_and_title_bold = posts.filter(post_with_border_and_title_bold=True)



    context = {
        'posts':posts,
        'commercial_post':commercial_post,
        'post_with_border':post_with_border, 
        'post_title_bold':post_title_bold, 
        'post_with_border_and_title_bold':post_with_border_and_title_bold, 
        }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

index.html:

```
{% if post_with_border AND commercial_post %}
    {% for abc in posts %}         
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="border border-danger">
                <img src="{{abc.picture.url}}">
            </a>
            <h1>
                <a href="#" class="SomeClass"> {{abc.title}}
                </a>
            </h1> 
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% else %}  

    {% for abc in normal_post %}         
        <div>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="{{abc.picture.url}}">
            </a>
            <h6>
                <a href="#"> {{abc.title}}
                </a>
            </h6> 
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

i want to make it to list if its a commercial post it should have a border and a H1 in title but if its a normal post it should have no border and H6. But the problem is it shows all posts with border and H1. 
I need your help please

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider restructuring your model.

models.py

```
class post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='somewhere/dir')
    active_post = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    commercial_post = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__ (self):
    return self.title
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    posts= post.objects.filter(active_post=True)

    context = {
        'posts':posts,
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
{% for post in posts %}         
    <div>
        {% if post.commercial_post %}
        <a href="#" class="border border-danger">
            <img src="{{post.picture.url}}">
        </a>
        <h1>
            <a href="#" class="SomeClass"> {{post.title}}
            </a>
        </h1> 
        {% else %}
        <a href="#">
            <img src="{{post.picture.url}}">
        </a>
        <h6>
            <a href="#"> {{post.title}}
            </a>
        </h6> 
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You're checking whether the post is commercial before you've looped through them, I think what you want is:

```html
{% for post in posts %}         
    {% if post.commercial_post is True %}
    // border & h1 tags, etc.
    {% else %
    // other stuff
{% endfor %}
```

I would go further and just use the if statement to set a class on the div, you can then dictate how that particular class is styled in the CSS - this would make your template much cleaner.

Furthermore, if your logic is simply that a commercial post has certain formatting then you should remove all the other fields in your model and from the views.py:

```
post_with_colored_border = models.BooleanField(default=False)
post_title_bold = models.BooleanField(default=False)
post_with_border_and_title_bold = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```